# Watson Assistant's trouble identifying State abbreviations and names

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm noticing that Watson is having trouble IDing "HI" for Hawaii and "WI" for Wisconson. It also doesn't do well with certain names like "Logan" and "Abbey."

They are system entities so I don't see an option to edit them in the Improve tab.

Has anyone dealt with this? I've tried a few work-arounds but haven't gotten anything to work well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could [define your own entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities) for the states and shortnames, e.g., `@states` with values for each state. If you know where those entities are mentioned, then you could look into [contextual entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-contextual-entities). Keep the system entities on and compare to how your own entities are recognized.

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to combine them... Use the system entities and augment the ones that it has trouble with. I tried "@sys-person || @names" but the " || " made its way into the variable itself and posted in the conversation. "Hi, || Abbey"

Comment: What do you plan to do with the variable? You could work with what is in the processing object.

Comment: I'm working on lead gen. "Who am I speaking with" "Chris" "Hi Chris, where would you like to go" "HI" "We have jobs in Hawaii" (collect contact info)